# wcf methods soap message format

Tags: wcf, soap

I know the defined soap message format.

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"
xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsa:To>http://localhost:5000/axis2/services/xdsrepositoryb</wsa:To>
    <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:AFBE87CB65FD88AC4B1220879854302</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:Action>urn:ihe:iti:2007:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSet-b</wsa:Action>
</soapenv:Header>
<soapenv:Body>
    <xdsb:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequest xmlns:xdsb="urn:ihe:iti:xds-b:2007">
        <lcm:SubmitObjectsRequest xmlns:lcm="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:lcm:3.0">
            <rim:RegistryObjectList xmlns:rim="urn:oasis:names:tc:ebxml-regrep:xsd:rim:3.0">
                <rim:ExtrinsicObject id="Document01" mimeType="text/plain"/>
            </rim:RegistryObjectList>
        </lcm:SubmitObjectsRequest>
        <xdsb:Document id="Document01">base64 content goes here</xdsb:Document>
    </xdsb:ProvideAndRegisterDocumentSetRequest>
</soapenv:Body>
```

I want to write a wcf service to exposed a method that can consume that kind of soap meassage.

I just don't know the relationship between the soap message and wcf method. Be more specific, what's the relationship between wcf methods, parameters and soap meassage ?

How can I write a wcf method that conform to the soap meassage above ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you can probably build a data contract that matches this particular example by working your way backwards, it is not generally a good idea. The sample might not be representative of the data that can be passed. Instead, you will be much better off by obtaining an official WSDL document or a set of XSDs that describe the contract.

If you're curious how a particular WCF message looks like in raw SOAP form, the easiest way to see that is probably to enable WCF tracing and look at the trace.